# How to implement client side Twitter login for website?

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

We are developing a node.js based API and responding client side website. In future same API will cater mobile apps' requests. The problem is we want to create client side Login for Facebook, Google+ and Twitter.

Login for Facebook and Google are successful but Twitter doesnot allow client side login. Any help on how to implement twitter login from client side is needed.

We cannot use server side Login as it won't work in future when we will integrate mobile apps.

We did not use passport.js as it is server based and responds with server side generated templates. which won't work for mobile apps.

Any suggestions workaround or help is welcomed.

Comment: Why is it even tagged node.js & Bro the problem is when you implement client side login on web your key's can be de-crypted and read by anyone (Though u can de-compile that and get keys out for the native app aswell).. Servers are safe :P or wait till OAuth2.0 comes in twitter or use somebodies 3p service for SSO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter does not allow sign in from client side. I am sorry there can't be workarounds. You should try some alternatives to work from server end. There are successful implementations of sign in for mobile apps.

May be you need research specific to your needs.

Comment: I think you are right my question is bit insensible.

Comment: https://satellizer.herokuapp.com/#/login

Answer (score 3):

> Twitter does not allow client side login. Any help on how to implement twitter login from client side is needed

It's not allowed; therefore you can't do it.

Comment: Any workaround might be possible, (asked with this intention).

Comment: If twitter is specifically disallowing you from doing it client side, then there is no work around that allows you to do it client side.